# log4j warning in xbasej integration

Tags: java, log4j

I am working with xBaseJ and in compilation I am not getting an error but while in compilation I am getting warnings like the following:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.xBaseJ.Util).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I reffered a lot. All of them saying about IDEs Eclipse and all. I dont use IDE, I am using notepad. What change I need to do to avoid this? Please help guys?? Dont mark this us duplicate please help.

Comment: I really think this is a duplicate, however: Do you have a log4j configuration file anywhere?

Comment: @SteveC I am putting log4j.properties file on Root where I run my .java file!!

Comment: Please show the content of your configuration file. Also show the output when running your program with `-Dlog4j.debug=true` in the command line

Comment: @SteveC I am running the program javac test.java then java test. After that I get that warnings I put above. Reffered  this to create properties file 'http://programming.mvergel.com/2013/01/warn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for.html'

Comment: @SteveC now no warning but getting something like this [2014-10-17 11:12:08,370]DEBUG     0[main] - org.xBaseJ.Util.getPropertiesFile(U
til.java:429) - Searched for org.xBaseJ.properties as C:\TIPL\GCST\org.xBaseJ.pr
operties

Comment: Seems like it is working then...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63200/discussion-between-androidgenx-and-steve-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the log4j.property file in Root where java files resides and then make log4j.properties file like the following:

```
log4j.rootCategory=FATAL, O

log4j.appender.O=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender

log4j.appender.O.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.O.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
```

@SteveC helped me to do this, Special thanks to him!!